# "No user found" while trying to log into aspx based website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm currently trying to log into an aspx based website but unfortunatly, I constantly get an error of no user found. (i know i have one because i can log in)

this is the code I have so far

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


requested_website = input('Please put in the name of the website you wish to test: ')
username = input('Please enter your username to login: ')
password = input('Please enter your password to login: ')


urls = Connection.get_login_url(requested_website.lower())
login_url = urls[0]
follow_up_url = urls[1]
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"}


s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
r = s.get(login_url, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

VIEWSTATE = soup.find(id='__VIEWSTATE')['value']
VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = soup.find(id='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')['value']

login_data={"__VIEWSTATE":VIEWSTATE,
"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
'UserName': username,
'Password': password}

r = s.post(login_url, data=login_data, verify=False)
print(r.url)

r = s.get(follow_up_url, verify=False)
print(r.url)
```

I hope you guys/gals can help me